# Low Resting Heart Rate but high bp

Tags: blood-pressure, heart-rate

My resting heart rate is around 50 bpm but my blood pressure is around 122/78. Is this unhealthy?

Comment: If you are fairly healthy and active then it is probably fine. But we really can't tell you that for sure online.

Comment: Go and talk to a doctor of your choice about it. They will know best what to do. **We can't provide medical diagnosis on Health.SE**. Only a doctor can!

Comment: What the others said. Probably great numbers but for all we know they're because you're taking meds or have a serious medical condition. This is why we can't answer the question.

Comment: My resting heart rate is 45. So don't worry, it's not necessarily bad; but only a doctor can say for sure if it is natural for you or dangerous.